# C# and multi-level reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a very complex object for which I am trying to write validation methods.  The information comes in, is serialized into the object and then I'm trying to do one of two things:

1. Check if the required fields have data
2. For those fields that have default values that can be used, if no value exists, set the field to the default value.

A simplified version of the JSON data looks as follows:

```
{
    "User": {
        "Name": "John Dude",
        "Department": "Sales"
    },
    
    "IDNumber": "23-0019872",
    "Addresses": [{
            "Street": "123 One St",
            "City": "Pittsville",
            "State": "CA",
            "Zip": "95432"
        },
        {
            "Street": "987 Dead End Dr",
            "City": "Nowhere",
            "State": "MI",
            "Zip": "45987"
        }
    ]
}
```

So my complex object has simple fields (string, int, bool, etc.), objects (User), and lists of objects (Addresses).

In my config file I have a list of data to check.  So the various fields are either like .User or Addresses.Street.  Nothing before the dot indicates the element is at the root and if it has something before the dot, it means that I have to check that object for a field.

I would think that checking the fields should be just a simple matter of using reflection.  It doesn't matter what kind of object it is accessing, so long as the value is not null or empty, it is enough to pass this validation level (more specific checks will come later).

I'm able to check the first level fields (User, IDNumber, and Address) with the standard code.

```
if (messageData.GetType().GetProperty(FullField[1]).ToString() == null ||
    messageData.GetType().GetProperty(FullField[1]).ToString() == String.Empty) {
       wasFieldFound = false;
}
```

The problem comes when I'm trying to check the complex object fields or the list object fields.

```
var container = messageData.GetType().GetProperty(FullField[0]);
string ContainerName = container.Name;
string[] ListElements = 
     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ListFields"].ToString().Split('|');
bool isList = false;

foreach (string Element in ListElements) {
    if (ContainerName.Equals(Element))
       isList = true;
}

if (!isList) {
   if (container.GetType().GetProperty(FullField[1]).ToString() == null ||
       container.GetType().GetProperty(FullField[1]).ToString().Equals(String.Empty))
            wasFieldFound = false;
}
```

In the case where the item is just a complex object, the field I am checking is read into the string array FullField (so User.Name is split into FullField[0] = User and FullField[1] = Name).  The variable container is getting the User element but the check on FullField[1] is null.  I've thought about trying to cast the container to another variable of the correct type but I've not had any luck with that.

The short question is how do you get an object via reflextion and then access a field or property of that object via reflextion?

Comment: Sounds like you should just use DataAnnotations such as `StringLength` attribute, and nullability constraints. It seems silly to try enforce this yourself when the serialzier can do it for you.

Comment: Have you deserialized your json into the actual type? If you have, then why do you need reflection to do validation? If you haven't, then why not deserialize payload into concrete type?

Comment: The NewtonSoft serializer's `JObject` mechanism allows you to look at the in-memory representation of JSON kinda-sorta like a Dictionary of Dictionaries. The `System.Text.Json` serializer doesn't work as well in this situation. Build a set of rules (likely in JSON) and then apply those rules to that representation. I've done something similar, but I no longer have access to that code

Comment: It's unclear to me why you would need reflection to do all that. I'd also recommend FluentValidation.

Comment: @Charlieface The problem with placing the validation in DataAnnotations is that not all fields are required all the time.  Based on values of some fields, other fields may not be required and therefore not provided.

Comment: @JohanP They are deserialized into types.  The problem is that the string fields are more than happy to deserialize into empty strings if they are not provided.  Also some fields are not required as they have default values so it is perfectly fine if they are not there so they are nullable variables

Comment: @Flydog57 I started out just navigating the JSON for the verification.  The problem that I ran into was that in two specific situations, the data has to be changed.  I ran into several problems with altering the values of the data while it was being held as a JSON string or a JObject.  I turned to this method in order to deal with those issues.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods To reduce the amount of code mostly.  I'm storing the required fields in configuration as delimited strings.  If the Name Field of the User object is required, then I'm storing that as User.Name.  That means at runtime I could need to check both User.Name and each of the Addresses.Zip fields.  That means accessing two different object types.  I shouldn't have to define the object type just to see if information is contained in the field.

I'm guessing there may be a way to do this with generics now that I'm thinking about it .  I'll look to research that tonight

Comment: If you are doing research anyway: I highly suggest to checkout [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/). I am not affiliated with the project but a happy user. It let's you define sophisticated validations _outside_ of your Model classes and it is very easily testable (so you can test if the validation actually validates as expected).

Comment: Still you could define an `OnDeserialized` method for example if you are using Json.NET